# Twilio Studio - SalesForce

Tags: salesforce, twilio, ivr, twilio-programmable-voice, twilio-studio

Planning to use Twilio Voice / Studio to build the IVR system / conversation tree.
I would like to know will there is a way to push the user's response (conversation audio) with the IVR systems to salesforce ?
Would like to persist the conversation between the user & IVR to Salesforce.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information on your Twilio setup. Do you have a server? What is it running?

Answer (score 0):

You could export parameters easily by using a HTTP Request widget or a Function widget and the widget set KEY:VALUE parameters which you can send out